# Jmeter Assertion failure reason

Tags: api, jmeter, http-post

I'm running a test on Jmeter. this is part of the sampler result-

```
Load time: 520
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 520
Size in bytes: 504
Headers size in bytes: 458
Body size in bytes: 46
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 201
Response message: Created
```

so I have added 'Response Assertion' that configured as follows-

Apply to:Main sample only, Response Field to test:Response Code, Pattern Matching Rules:Equals, Patterns to test: 201.

when running it, the request fails and the reason is this:

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: code expected to equal /

****** received  : 201[[[  ]]]

****** comparison: 201[[[

]]]

/
```

What is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in description you specified

> Response Field to test:Response Message

by mistake, since the failure points to the fact that you compared Response code.

Given that, looks like you accidentally have newline character(s) after "201", which is(are) invisible, but cause comparison to fail. So just remove any spaces/newlines after "201". Make sure that Patterns to test is exactly 201, nothing else.

Comment: you are right. I actually thought I've tried it. only deleting the parameter completely and re-enter it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Is

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: code expected to equal /
****** received  : 201[[[  ]]]

****** comparison: 201[[[

]]]
/
```

solution of problems:-

If you add link in `Server Name or IP` like this  `lifecharger.org/archives/` then need to change it to `lifecharger.org`

Add you link path in `Path`  `/archives/` then it will be work.

Thanks